# how do i install tween max on hp 550

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a problem getting tween max, do you download it free to your computer or do one have to buy it? currently am doing a site school project and i do need tween max and the others. guys i hope u don't mind hooking me up with this information; my project is in due on friday.....i need aid guys

thanks

Comment: Have you found the TweenMax homepage? http://blog.greensock.com/tweenmaxas3/

Answer (score 2):

You just download it, put it in your classpath, and off you go. You only need to buy a license if you are using it for commercial work where the site itself generates direct revenue (though donations are always welcome).